# Find text with regular expression and replace in file

Tags: python, file-io, str-replace

I would like to find text in file with regular expression and after replace it to another name. I have to read file line by line at first because in other way re.match(...) can`t find text.

My test file where I would like to make modyfications is (no all, I removed some code):

```
//...
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_TESTSUITE_H
#define FUNCTIONS_TESTSUITE_H
//...
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(FunctionsTS)
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test)
{
  std::string l_dbConfigDataFileName = "../../Config/configDB.cfg";
  DB::FUNCTIONS::DBConfigData l_dbConfigData;
//...
}
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
//...
```

Now python code which replace the configDB name to another. I have to find configDB.cfg name by regular expression because all the time the name is changing. Only the name, extension not needed.

Code:

```
import fileinput
import re

myfile = "Tset.cpp"

#first search expression - ok. working good find and print configDB
with open(myfile) as f:
  for line in f:
    matchObj = re.match( r'(.*)../Config/(.*).cfg(.*)', line, re.M|re.I)
    if matchObj:
      print "Search : ", matchObj.group(2)

#now replace searched expression to another name - so one more time find and replace - another way - not working - file after run this code is empty?!!!
for line in fileinput.FileInput(myfile, inplace=1):    
    matchObj = re.match( r'(.*)../Config/(.*).cfg(.*)', line, re.M|re.I)
    if matchObj:
      line = line.replace("Config","AnotherConfig")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.FileInput):

> Optional in-place filtering: if the keyword argument inplace=1 is passed to fileinput.input() or to the FileInput constructor, the file is moved to a backup file and **standard output is directed to the input file** (if a file of the same name as the backup file already exists, it will be replaced silently).

What you need to do is just print `line` in every step of the loop. Also, you need to print line without additional newline, so you can use `sys.stdout.write` from `sys` module. As a result:

```
import fileinput
import re
import sys

...
for line in fileinput.FileInput(myfile, inplace=1):    
    matchObj = re.match( r'(.*)../Config/(.*).cfg(.*)', line, re.M|re.I)
    if matchObj:
      line = line.replace("Config","AnotherConfig")
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

**ADDED:**
Also I assume that you need to replace `config.cfg` to `AnotherConfig.cfg`. In this case, you can do something like this:

```
import fileinput
import re
import sys

myfile = "Tset.cpp"

regx = re.compile(r'(.*?\.\./Config/)(.*?)(\.cfg.*?)')

for line in fileinput.FileInput(myfile, inplace=1):    
    matchObj = regx.match(line, re.M|re.I)
    if matchObj:
        sys.stdout.write(regx.sub(r'\1AnotherConfig\3', line))
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

You can read about function `sub` here: [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you, you want to change in the line:

```
std::string l_dbConfigDataFileName = "../../Config/configDB.cfg";
```

just the file name 'configBD' to some other file name and rewrite the file.

First, I would suggest writing to a new file and changing the file names in case something goes wrong. Rather than use re.match use re.sub if there is a match it will return the line altered if not it will return the line unaltered -- just write it to a new file. Then change the filenames -- the old file to .bck and the new file to the old file name.

```
import re
import os

regex = re.compile(r'(../config/)(config.*)(.cfg)', re.IGNORECASE)

oldF = 'find_config.cfg'
nwF = 'n_find_config.cfg'
bckF = 'find_confg.cfg.bck'

with open ( oldF, 'r' ) as f, open ( nwF, 'w' ) as nf :
    lns = f.readlines()
    for ln in lns:
        nln = re.sub(regex, r'\1new_config\3', ln )
        nf.write  ( nln )


os.rename ( oldF, bckF )
os.rename ( nwF, oldF )
```